# Hapi.response.File on reply completion

Tags: node.js

I'm using hapi.js as my api framework, and I've got a scenario where the GET path downloads a file (a temp file on the server).

On completion of the download, the server is suppose to delete the temp file.

At the moment, download of the file is done using Hapi.response.File

```
 var response = new Hapi.response.File(path);
 req.reply(response).header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + doc[0].file.name).header('Content-type', mimetype);
```

Is there a simple way to inject an 'on end' event function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it is considered simple, but you can hook into Hapi's `onPreResponse` server event, and from there listen for the `finish` response event. According to the Hapi documentation the `finish` event is

> emitted when the response finished writing but before the client
>   response connection is ended.

So should be safe to remove the temporary file on that event.

Something like this should do the trick (based on Hapi v6.0.x):

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {
    // other code here, e.g. boom checking

    if ( ... ) {    // Test to see if the request was to download tmp file
         request.response.once('finish', function () {
             // delete tmp file here
         });
    }

    reply(request.response);
});
```

Also, there is neater way of serving a file:

```
reply.file(path, [options])
```

Check out the docs [here](http://hapijs.com/api#replyfilepath-options)